# Area Calculation: Different result between GEE and ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-earth-engine

Can anyone explain why I got different area calculation result between GEE and ArcGIS software?
This my GEE code:

```
for(var x = 1; x < 5; x++) {

  var cal = image_class.eq(x).multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
                             .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(), 
                              aoi, 20, null, null, false, 1e13, 1)

  print('ID' + x ,cal,ee.Number(cal.values().get(0)).divide(1e6).multiply(100)) 

}
```

These the results (hectares):

GEE:

- ID: 1 = 13,637
- ID: 2 = 30,314
- ID: 3 = 5,663
- ID: 4 = 648

GIS SOFWARE (PROJECTION: WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_49S):

- ID: 1 = 15,923
- ID: 2 = 27,678
- ID: 3 = 6,159
- ID: 4 = 579

Comment: What GIS software

Comment: ArcMap 
I used Raster to Polygon tools then calculated it

Comment: You didn't specify a projection for Google Earth Engine.

Comment: Perhaps, you have any documentation or link for that? I really have no idea about it.